# code crash at the moment when finish the scan and encrypt

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, usb

I want to make this code work, but when I try to plug in my flash device, and find all files scanned that contains it says:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
>   'Screenshot from 2016-11-30 16-53-48.png'

How can I fix to make it run correctly?

Output from scan:

```
letter: E:\
There were 1 drives added: set(['E']). Newly mounted drive letter is E:\
['Screenshot from 2016-11-30 16-53-48.png', 'Screenshot from 2016-11-30 16-57-30.png', 'Screenshot from 2016-11-30 16-57-43.png', 'Screenshot from 2016-11-30 16-58-14.png', 'script.py', 'private_key.key', 'public_key.key', 'python-2.7.12.msi', 'pycrypto-2.6.1.win32-py2.7.exe', 'pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe', 'Learning Python, 5th Edition.pdf', 'python_book_01.pdf', 'python_tutorial.pdf', 'Violent Python - A Cookbook for Hackers, Forensic Analysts, Penetration Testers and Security Engineers.pdf', 'Black_Hat_Python_Python_Programming_for_Hackers_and_Pentesters.pdf', 'CE_149_Ciberseguridad.pdf', 'windows 7 all in one 32bits y 64bits.iso', 'test.txt']
```

My code:

```
from ctypes import windll
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
    from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
    import string
    import time
    import os, sys

    def get_drives():
        drives = []
        bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
        for letter in string.uppercase:
            if bitmask & 1:
                drives.append(letter)
            bitmask >>= 1
        return drives

    def encrypt_file(filename):
        print filename

    def list_files(path):
        files = []
        for name in os.listdir(str(path)):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name)):
                files.append(name)
        return files 

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print 'Searching usb...'
        while True:
            before = set(get_drives())
            time.sleep(5)
            after = set(get_drives())
            drives = after - before
            delta = len(drives)
            if (delta):
                for drive in drives:
                    if os.system("cd " + drive + ":") == 0:
                        newly_mounted = '%c:\\'%(drive)
                        encrypt_files = list_files(newly_mounted)
                        print "letter: "+newly_mounted
                        print "There were %d drives added: %s. Newly mounted drive letter is %s" % (delta, drives, newly_mounted)
                        for x in encrypt_files:
                            if os.path.basename(x).startswith("(encrypted)"):
                                print "%s is already encrypted" %str(x)
                                pass

                            else:
                                encrypt_file(encrypt_files)
                                print "Done encrypting %s" %str(x)
                                os.remove(x) 
                    else:
                        print "Sorry, I couldn't find any newly mounted drives."
```